# app_id, app_key, api_path for local BigchainDB installation

Tags: configuration, bigchaindb

I've just finished installing bigchaindb and when i browse to http://localhost:9984/ I get the following response.

```
{"api":{"v1":{"assets":"/api/v1/assets/","docs":"https://docs.bigchaindb.com/projects/server/en/v1.3.0/http-client-server-api.html","outputs":"/api/v1/outputs/","statuses":"/api/v1/statuses/","streams":"ws://localhost:9985/api/v1/streams/valid_transactions","transactions":"/api/v1/transactions/"}},"docs":"https://docs.bigchaindb.com/projects/server/en/v1.3.0/","keyring":[],"public_key":"5USUyXwDGPh7yWiHqihRB6ebX2zw5AxydFc7DsTPUr6m","software":"BigchainDB","version":"1.3.0"}
```

I've been looking for tutorials on how to interact with this db and I found the following tutorial https://www.bigchaindb.com/developers/getstarted/

I'm a bit unclear on how to retrieve the app_id, app_key and api_path for my local instance. Can some point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can sign up for a (free) account on the BigchainDB Testnet. Once you do that, it will give each of your applications (including the initial default one) an app_id and an app_key. To sign up for a testnet account, go to:

https://testnet.bigchaindb.com/

Comment: Just to clarify do we need to sign up to get an app_id and app_key for a locally hosted instance as well? I thought it was for the testnet environment

Comment: The app_id and app_key are specific to the BigchainDB Testnet. You don't need to include those headers in requests to a locally-hosted instance.